# Is it possible to use wildcards in webpack's require.context calls?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I only want Webpack to look at files in directories called ".stories", but they can be located anywhere arbitrarily in the `src/` directory structure.

For example, my naïve attempt at this looks as follows:

```
/*
src/
  some.story.js <-- don't get this
  |_components/
    |_Button/
      |_ .stories/ <--
        |_ index.js <-- ignore this
        |_ utils.js <-- ignore this
        |_ main.story.js <-- get this
    |_Forms/
      |_ TextField
        |_ .stories/ <-- same kind of thing
   */




// require.context API
// require.context(directory to search, shouldSearchSubDirs?, fileNameRegex)

require.context('src/**/.stories', true, /\.story\.js$/)
```

So far it seems as if the API wants me to do all my pattern matching on the file names. But the file names alone aren't enough information to exclude `.story.js` files in other directories. I want to allow for `.story.js` files outside of `.stories/` directories, and have Webpack ignore them.

Is this possible? What am I missing?

When reading the [official documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context), the implication is that the first argument specifies one specific directory:

> It allows you to pass in a directory to search, a flag indicating
>   whether subdirectories should be searched too, and a regular
>   expression to match files against.

One reading of this is antithetical to my goal, but nothing clearly states this is impossible. Webpack is a complex tool and it's easy to misunderstand its capabilities.

Answer (score 5):

I know it's been a long time. But I will fix the answer for other people.

```
require.context('../src/components/', true, /\.stories\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.story.js$/);
```